# MySQL - join query results vertically

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a summary report for to capture daily stats. Basically I need the outcome similar to:

```
Table_Name       Updated_Rows       Created_Rows      Date
Table 1          10                 5                 2019-04-23
Table 2          17                 55                2019-04-23
```

Now I can fetch the individual values using basic commands:

```
select count(*) as created_rows 
from accounts 
where date(updated_at) = date(now())
```

and

```
select count(*) as created_rows 
from accounts 
where date(created_at) = date(now())
```

Can also combine the data using the UNINON ALL,

```
(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name='accounts')
UNION ALL
(select count(*) as created_rows from accounts where date(created_at) = date(now()))
UNION ALL
(select count(*) as updated_rows from accounts where date(updated_at) = date(now()))
```

However the output I get is kind of stacked vertically and I wish to retain the labels/column names and would want to add data row by row for all the tables I want to assess.

I am sure there is an easier way but I can't seem the find a way out to get this done. Don't need the final query, just help me with a direction to look towards.

Answer (score 0):

For a single table, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 'account' AS 'Table_Name'
,      SUM(date(updated_at) = date(now())) 'Updated_Rows' 
,      SUM(date(created_at) = date(now())) 'Created_Rows'
,      date(now()) AS 'Date'
FROM accounts
```

where `SUM(date(updated_at) = date(now()))` is basically the same as

```
 IF(SUM(date(updated_at) = date(now())), 1, 0)
```

Then **UNION ALL** result from other tables with the similar query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following (untested):

```
select '@x' as table_name,
(select count(*) FROM @x and date(created_at) = date(now())) as created_rows,
(select count(*) FROM @x and date(updated_at) = date(now())) as updated_rows
```

As part of a prepared statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) or proc (https://medium.com/@peter.lafferty/mysql-stored-procedures-101-6b4fe230967) or just union to get multiple tables (note that you'd have to change some syntax). I'm not sure how you need to run this, so I'm not sure what exactly you need, what kind of performance you're after, if you're just going to make a script and manually select the tables or if you're trying to run this on all tables, etc.

EDIT: jxc's query is much better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? If so, make sure to change the table names in the subsequent `UNION ALL` queries.

```
    SELECT 
    'accounts' AS TableName,
    SUM(DATE(updated_at) = DATE(NOW())) AS updated_rows,
    SUM(DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW())) AS created_rows,
    DATE(NOW()) AS `Date`
    FROM
    accounts

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    'accounts2' AS TableName,
    SUM(DATE(updated_at) = DATE(NOW())) AS updated_rows,
    SUM(DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW())) AS created_rows,
    DATE(NOW()) AS `Date`
    FROM
    accounts2

   and so forth....
```

**EDIT** This query is identical to jxc's query posted earlier